# Project React-Leaflet map in different projection

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, react, proj4js, proj4leaflet

I am working on a college project that deals with MAPS. Our project is related to mapping the location of stadiums for the recent FIFA worldcup. The tileserver url provided to us is custom.

When I use OSM maps, the tiles for the country of Qatar at Z 10 show up properly the z/x/y in the url is 10/436/656. But the tiles in the custom tile server for the same location (Hamad International Airport) is around these numbers of z/y/x 10/106387/83602.

I am using React-Leaflet map and have been searching for a solution for nearly a month to reproject the y&x coordinate but to no avail.

How can I fix this?

Sorry for the confusion caused due to missing code:

```
      <MapContainer
        center={position}
        zoom={state.zoom}
        style={{ minHeight: 900, height: "100%" }}
        //below Proj.CRS is from proj4leaflet
        crs={
          new Proj.CRS(
            "EPSG:3857",
            "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs",
            {
              resolutions: [
                140, 70.0, 27.999999999999996, 13.999999999999998,
                6.999999999999999, 2.8, 1.4, 0.7, 0.28, 0.2, 0.14,
              ],
            }
          )
        }
      >
        <LayersControl>
          <LayersControl.BaseLayer name="Base" checked>
            <TileLayer
              attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMapContainer</a> contributors'
              // url="https://maps.axepts.com/arcgis/rest/services/Tiled_en/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"
              url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
          </LayersControl.BaseLayer>
        </LayersControl>
```

This url works:

> https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
>
> With values z/x/y: 10/436/656 that shows Hamad Airport

This url does not work:

> https://maps.axepts.com/arcgis/rest/services/Tiled_en/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}
>
> With values 10/436/656 it should ideally show Hamad Airport but after a lot of scrolling/panning/dragging I found Hamad Airport & Qatar in general at z/y/x: 10/106387/83602
>
> Output(Tile) in this link https://imgur.com/a/evDBlFO

The order of z/y/x being interchanged with z/x/y doesnot affect the output.

It seems the tile numbers are very different with OSM compared to the ArcGIS instance at this server.

The PNG at the end doesnt affect the output, just the {y}/{x} values are way off.

A Screenshot shared to me by the instructor:
[image: Coordinate / Projection]

https://imgur.com/a/uTrR66B

Comment: You have `proj4js` and `proj4leaflet` tags in your question, but you are not using it in your code.

Comment: @TomazicM I had used it but it did'nt work so removed the code related to it to simplify the base code. If i get a solution using anyone of these will be greatful as i feel a solution lies with them. Do you have any idea how to solve this problem using them ?

Comment: Code related to the `proj4js` and `proj4leaflet` is key part of the problem/solution, so whatever you had tried, please include it. What's also needed is complete info returned from `https://maps.axepts.com/arcgis/rest/services/Tiled_en/MapServer/` call, since `https://maps.axepts.com/` is not publicly available.

Comment: @TomazicM Hey, I have updated the question with the necessary edits ! Thanks in advance ! :) 
I am also checking with them if there is any publically accessible link available!

Comment: What's is still missing is output from `https://maps.axepts.com/arcgis/rest/services/Tiled_en/MapServer/` call. This gives complete info about tile layer parameters (crs, extent, zooms, zoom resolutions).

Comment: The output is a tile image. Imgur link attached below the map.axepts.com url. Other than the image nothing else comes. Unless you want me to provide the headers of the response

Comment: At zoom level 10 the largest x and y numbers should be 1024 (2 to the power of 10).  You can see this in action at  - https://missinglink.github.io/leaflet-spatial-prefix-tree/

Comment: Your tile from imgur shows decent detail.  Is it possibly zoom level 14?  That would allow  16384 columns and rows.

Comment: @CaryH it is Zoom 10 z=10 not 14

Comment: Output from `https://maps.axepts.com/arcgis/rest/services/Tiled_en/MapServer/` call shouldn't be a tile, but something like output from this call: `https://gis.arso.gov.si/arcgis/rest/services/DOF_2016/MapServer`.

Comment: It shows url restricted. Also based on the available information. Can the problem be solved?

Comment: No, info that should come from `https://maps.axepts.com/arcgis/rest/services/Tiled_en/MapServer/` (projection, extent, zoom resolutions) is essential for the solution.

Comment: I will have to check with my instructor. Mostly by Monday should have the details. Thanks @TomazicM

Answer (score 0):

Can you load 2 urls and an if statement that if zoom > 10 use url #2 which would swap the x and y?

```
url1="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
url2="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{y}/{x}.png"
```

If you look at how map events are handled in this post: [MapEvents in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70378084/is-it-possible-to-display-react-leafletjs-markers-on-specific-zoom-levels)

Comment: Thanks for the response but this is not what i was looking for.